# Match pattern append line but exclude pattern line

Tags: sed, awk

I want to add

```
 <br \>
```

at the end of each line in-between the tag

```
 <div> ... </div>
```

source file

```
 bla bala
 <div>
 bla bala
 bla bala
 bla bala
 </div>
 bla bala
```

I want to have out put like the

```
 bla bala
 <div>
 bla bala <br \>
 bla bala <br \>
 bla bala <br \>
 </div>
 bla bala
```

I tried this but it also adds   to the  tag line

```
 sed -i '' '/<pre\>/,/<\/pre\>/ s/$/<br \\>/' test.txt
```

also tried this

```
 sed -i '' '/<pre\>/,/<\/pre\>/{/$/<br \\>/;}' test.txt
```

How can I exclude the line that has match pattern?

update: can you do this with sed?

Comment: You are calling into problems parsing `html` with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/<div>/,/<\/div>/s/[^>]$/<br \/>/' test.html
```

It will apply a substitute command to a range of lines described by the beginning and ending pattern separated by a `,`:

```
/<div>/,/<\/div>/
```

The substitute command (simplified):

```
s/$/<br \/>/
```

... will replace line endings with `<br />` tags.

Unfortunately the pattern range includes the opening and closing `<div>` tags and there is no way to tell `sed` that it should use only the lines between the start and end pattern. That's why I've added `[^>]` to avoid that `\n` will be placed after the tags, which is the final command:

```
s/[^>]$/<br \/>/
```

Another solution to apply the substitution only to the lines between the `<div>` tags could look like this (maybe more clean and general):

```
 sed '/<div>/,/<\/div>/ {/<div>/n; /<\/div>/ ! {s/$/<br \/>/}}' test.html
```

It will select the range including the opening and closing div tags and the line between them as in the example above, but then skips the opening `<div>` tag using the `n` command and the closing `</div>` using the `!` before the following block between the curly braces. For more info check [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35a)

---

However, although I like to have fun using `sed` I would not use regexes to manipulate html or xml documents in a real world application. I would use [`xslt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) for this.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this makes it:

```
$ awk '/<\/div>/ {p=0} p{$0=$0"<br \>"} /<div>/ {p=1} 1' file
bla bala
<div>
bla bala<br \>
bla bala<br \>
bla bala<br \>
</div>
bla bala
```

Comment: Well, hek2gml posted a good answer with `sed`. I posted with `awk`, so all together we cover both tags you used for your question.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<div>/,/<\/div>/!b;//!s/$/ <br \\>/' file
```

Sed has a feature whereby an empty regexp takes the previous regexp value.